# Is it required that I get immunized for yellow fever in order to go to Ghana?

Tags: health, ghana

Must I get a shot for yellow fever to visit Ghana?

Comment: Is there any reason *not* to get immunized given that Ghana is an endemic yellow fever country, the immunization is secure and risk-free and yellow fever is an extremely serious infection?

Answer (score 6):

Strictly, no because passengers arriving without a yellow fever vaccination certificate are subject to vaccination upon arrival, for which there is a fee.

Also, passengers leaving Ghana are required to present a yellow fever vaccination certificate upon departure.

[Ghana Embassy](http://www.ghanaembassy.nl/index.php/announcements/165-yellow-fever-vaccination-requirement-for-travelers-across-frontiers-of-ghana.html) for further details.